# redirection 301 with htaccess with variables in url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've searched answers on the forum but didn't worked for me.

I have rebuild an website using Wordpress and want to keep old urls.

old url:
`/bingo/play-bingo-40/review?reviews_id=16`

nwe url:
`https://website.com/product/the-new-url-of-play-bingo-40/`

I have tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^reviews_id=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^bingo/play-bingo-40/review https://website.com/product/the-new-url-of-play-bingo-40/? [R=301]
```

Any one?

Comment: try this Redirect 301 /bingo/play-bingo-40/review?reviews_id=16 https://website.com/product/the-new-url-of-play-bingo-40/

Comment: You can use simple 301 redirect plugin. https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/ visit this site and read document and use this plugin.

Comment: Thanks but already tried, doesn't work.

Comment: what does it do when you go to the Old url?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use anything from the query string, so you don't need to capture with a `RewriteCond`. You seem to use part of the request URL, so you must capture this one

```
RewriteRule ^bingo/(.+?)/review https://example.com/product/the-new-url-of-$1/? [R,L]
```

To learn more about mod_rewrite generally and regular expressions particularly, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html. Another good reference for regular expressions is http://www.regular-expressions.info/